# PHP user profile page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to make a website with users on it, and I'm trying to create a script so that whenever a new user registers it will automatically create a user folder and profile for them but when I try to register it doesn't create the files,
 could someone please help me with this, Thanks

```html
<?php

    include "inc/header.php";

    $newfolder = $username;


    if (!mkdir($newfolder, 0777, true)) {
        die('Failed to create folders...');
    }


    $pagename = $username;

    $newFileName = './u/'.$username.'/'.$pagename.".php";
    $newFileContent = '<?php echo "something..."; ?>';
?>
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with JavaScript or HTML?

Comment: Why don't you save the user's details in a database? Later, you can retrieve *that* from the database and display/manipulate as per your logic.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul i do have it liked with a database

Comment: @vlaz they were the recommended tags so i used them

Comment: @meme well, if you don't do anything with either, you don't _need_ to use them. It isn't helping your question at all, as it just makes it less clear what you are asking.

Comment: In this line `if (!mkdir($newfolder,...`, `$newfolder` is not a complete directory path. RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Comment: you posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907971/creating-new-page-with-new-user and you never answered [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907971/creating-new-page-with-new-user#comment67120772_39907971) I left  you. What you posted is an exact duplicate and is related to this question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah sorry about that i started writing this then fell asleep then woke up and posted it then i saw your comment, thanks for the help

Comment: well you're up now ;-)

Comment: lovely; now you went and deleted your other question. I can't help you any further, voted to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To make a directory/file**

```
if (!file_exists("parent_folder/$username")) {
//Create a file with read write execute PERMISSIONS ENABLED 
//Please check :  your parent folder also must have 0777 permissions to avoid any kind of read write error
        mkdir("parent_folder/$username", 0777);
//now u have to create a FILE with .php
//now this file_put_contents is VERY importnant !
$pagename = $username ;
$newFileName = './parent_folder/$username/'.$pagename.".php";
$newFileContent = '<?php echo "something..."; ?>';

if (file_put_contents($newFileName, $newFileContent) !== false) {
//notify file is created 
    echo "File created (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
} else {
//notify u have error
    echo "Cannot create file (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
}

//now create ur .php file in user folder
        }
       else {
    echo "Your parent folder does not exist"
    }
```

**Now the possible error and some tips**

1) Most of people do fopen("filename_with_PATH", "w")
and expect that file will be generated in PATH folder !
Some times it might fall wrong (depends on version)

> fopen is meant to create a file in the directory where your php resides

2) **check ur php permission in php.ini** if u dont give php permission to write,remote access then u might get some errors (it will be displayed that u have error in my script)

3)For more info and tinkering [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Hope this will be helpful for you ..